# Vim how to add key binding that accepts input

Tags: c++, vim

I'm pretty new to vim but I'm trying to create some C++ IDE.

I'm used to ctrl f (or ctrl-shift-f) to help me find in files.. so I saw a plugin I liked called pss.

I'd like to replace ctrl-f with something that would accept input but still add parameters of it's own(*.cpp for example)..
I was thinking of something like:

how can I do it correctly?

```
noremap <C-f>:Pss $1 *.cpp
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may find http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4450 useful.

Comment: But I want something to default look only in *.cpp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have editing capabilities in the command-line, a commonly used approach just builds an incomplete mapping. You can position the cursor in the edit location, like this:

```
:noremap <C-f> :Pss  *.cpp<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

After triggering the mapping (via `<C-f>`), you can insert the search pattern, and then trigger the search via `<CR>`.

#### Alternative

You can query for input via the `input()` function; its result can be inserted into the command-line via `:execute`:

```
:noremap <C-f> :execute 'Pss' input('Pattern: ') '*.cpp'<CR>
```

Comment: very very nice, second alternative is way cooler, but first is a very good nice-to-know

Answer (score 0):

The default search hot-key is faster than the "Ctrl-F", you may type "/" in the normal mode, and continue input with your keywords. Once you need to search in many files, grep is your friend.

Comment: so even grep, how to default it to look in *.cpp?

Comment: @Alon: my way: alias finder='find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs grep' See man find -print0 to make it more robust.